# Вывод текста в окно Блокнота

Tags: python

У меня есть программа в которую для входа в аккаунт надо код но чтобы это не делать самому я решил дать эту задачу языку программирования python. Проблема в том что когда я пишу программу для ввода кода в приложение(блокнот) у меня не выводил текст в приложение. Я подумал может сбой и решил попробовать ещё раз. Когда я закрыл блокнот у меня начал вводиться код который изначально должен был ввестись в блокнот

```
import pyautogui as pag
import os

os.system('C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad')
pag.typewrite('1111', 1)
```

вот сам код, если можете пожалуйста помогите т.к. даже интернет не знает (ну или я не правильно формулирую запрос)

Comment: Какой вопрос то?

Comment: Нужно в какую-то форму для ввода кода текст автоматически ввести, который в файле хранится?

Comment: Как я понимаю, текст не вводится в нужное окно. Но оно, например, на момент ввода ещё может быть не активно (notepad не успел запуститься)

Comment: Блокнот запускается и после его запуска ничего не происходит но как только я его закрою у меня начинает выводиться код в pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` запускает команду, ждет ее завершения (у вас - закрытия окна блокнота), и только потом продолжается выполнение программы. Именно поэтому у вас печатать начинает только после закрытия блокнота.

Чтобы запустить, но не ждать завершения, нужно использовать [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) из модуля `subprocess`:

```
import pyautogui as pag
from subprocess import Popen
import time

process = Popen("C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad")

time.sleep(0.2)  # Небольшая пауза, чтобы окно успело появиться
pag.typewrite('1111', 1)
```

Если нужно принудительно дождаться закрытия блокнота, добавляете строку `process.wait()`.